How to add multiple listeners to a NATS JetStream consumer?
I've created a NATS JetStream publisher which publishes to a "Work Queue" in the following manner:
import nats 
import json
import asyncio

from pathlib import Path


NATS_URL = "nats://localhost:4222"

dummy_tasks = [
    ('traffic.download.URMO.v1.1', 1),
    ('traffic.download.URMO.v1.2', 2),
    ('traffic.download.URMO.v1.3', 3),
    ('traffic.download.NUMO.v1.1', 4),
    ('traffic.download.NUMO.v1.2', 5),
    ('traffic.download.URMO.v1.4', 6),
    ('traffic.download.URMO.v1.5', 7),
    ('traffic.download.NUMO.v1.3', 8),
]

async def main():

    # Create a work queue 

    nc = await nats.connect(NATS_URL)
    js = nc.jetstream()

    stream_config = nats.js.api.StreamConfig(
        name="traffic-download",
        subjects=["traffic.download.*.*.*"],
        retention=nats.js.api.RetentionPolicy.WORK_QUEUE,
    )

    await js.add_stream(stream_config)

    for task in dummy_tasks:
        msg_payload = json.dumps(task[1]).encode('utf-8')
        await js.publish(task[0], msg_payload)
        print(f"Sent message for task {task[0]}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    await nc.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    
    asyncio.run(main())


My goal now would be to have multiple instances (processes) which are able to listen to this stream and "pick off" tasks as they come in. As of now I'm only able to run one instance of the consumer script (code below) before encountering an error.
async def callback(msg):

    #payload = json.loads(msg.data.decode('utf-8'))
    #write_geojson(payload['path'], payload['bounds'])
    print(f"Received message for task {msg.subject}")


async def main():

    nc = await nats.connect(NATS_URL)
    js = nc.jetstream()

    await js.subscribe("traffic.download.*.*.*", stream="traffic-download", cb=callback)

    await asyncio.Event().wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

This is the error I get "hit" with when I run more than one(1) instance of the consumer script:
nats.js.errors.BadRequestError: nats: BadRequestError: code=400 err_code=10100 description='filtered consumer not unique on workqueue stream'
I know there's a lot of documentation on NATS online but I haven't been able to find anything specific to my case regarding Python. I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong.

My general advice with nats.py is to never, ever use js.subscribe() -- it's trying to do too much in a way that confuses which step it's performing is the one that failed (something you further confused here by not giving a full stack trace so we could see which specific request to the nats server made by js.subscribe() was the one to fail). Stick to explicit js.pull_subscribe_bind() after you've done an explicit js.add_consumer() -- and you probably want to be creating durable consumers so state isn't lost when all the workers have exited.
